# Merge two hash arrays into one without changing Key value pairs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Hi I have two hash arrays as follows

```
A = [{"name" => "rihan"}, {"name" => "gihan"}, {"name" => "mihan"}]
B = [{"value" => "true"}, {"value" => "true"}, {"value" => "true"}]
```

how to merge them into single hash array as 
    [{"name" => "rihan", "value" => true"]

As I need to verify them against the pipe delimited cucumber table converted in hashes
e.g |name|value
    |rihan|true|
    |gihan|true|

For cucumber table I am using below function to convert it into hashes

```
def create_hash_from_data_table table
 table.hashes.each do |hash| ; @table_hash = hash ; end
 return @table_hash
end
```

And for actual JSON response I am extracting it using recursive function
to above two hash arrays [A] and [B] but I am not sure how to merge them to compare with the cucumber data without overwriting or changing the duplicate values in A[] and B[].

I tried merge and recursive merge option
e.g. array1 = array2.merge(array1)

Kindly assist as merge method throws undefined method error

Comment: Can you express this in actual Ruby code? This helps us test solutions.

Comment: @tadman Updated the question with ruby code

Comment: This is not Ruby code. Is `a = [{"name" => "rihan"}, {"name" => "gihan"}, {"name" => "mihan"}]` what you mean?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Yes sorry for it. I will update it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is still very confusing. I am assuming that you have this input:

```
a = [{"name" => "rihan"}, {"name" => "gihan"}, {"name" => "mihan"}]
b = [{"value" => 1}, {"value" => 2}, {"value" => 3}]
```

And you desire this output:

```
[{"name"=>"rihan", "value"=>1},
 {"name"=>"gihan", "value"=>2},
 {"name"=>"mihan", "value"=>3}]
```

Which can be achieved with:

```
a.zip(b).map { |ar| ar.inject(:merge) }
```

Or in this specific case (where the arrays after zipping are always 2-element):

```
a.zip(b).map { |x,y| x.merge(y) }
```

As

```
a.zip(b) #=> [[{"name"=>"rihan"}, {"value"=>1}], [{"name"=>"gihan"}, {"value"=>2}], [{"name"=>"mihan"}, {"value"=>3}]]
```

And then each element of the array is mapped by merging all of its elements.

Or a bit more explicit version, with a simple loop:

```
a.size.times.with_object([]) do |i, output|
  output << a[i].merge(b[i])
end
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Other option, pairing elements from each array by index:

```
a.map.with_index { |h, i| h.merge(b[i]) }

a #=> [{"name"=>"rihan", :value=>"true"}, {"name"=>"gihan", :value=>"true"}, {"name"=>"mihan", :value=>"true"}]
```

Comment: iGian, I am having issues with merge but your earlier answer worked for me. Thanks for the help